# Should construct parameters be abstract or concrete classes when injecting <something>

Tags: java

You'll have to excuse my ignorance, I'm very new to Java.

Let's pretend I'm trying to create a repository.
I have an interface such as this:

```
public interface Repository<T, K>{
    T get(K id);
    // some more methods
}
```

And then a few concrete classes that implement this interface

```
public class RepositoryOne implements Repository<EntityOne, Long> {
    // methods
}


public class RepositoryTwo implements Repository<EntityTwo, Long> {
    // methods
}
```

And then some service that uses one of the concrete repository interface implementations.

My question is: **what is the correct way to write this service?** Here are some examples, all valid from a syntax point of view.

1st - concrete constructor parameter, concrete class member

```
public class SomeService{
    private final RepositoryOne repositoryOne;

    public SomeService(RepositoryOne repositoryOne) {
        this.repositoryOne = repositoryOne;
    }

    // methods
}
```

2nd - concrete constructor parameter, interface class member

```
public class SomeService{
    private final Repository<EntityOne, Long> repositoryOne;

    public SomeService(RepositoryOne repositoryOne) {
        this.repositoryOne = repositoryOne;
    }

    // methods
}
```

3rd - interface constructor parameter, interface class member

```
public class SomeService{
    private final Repository<EntityOne, Long> repositoryOne;

    public SomeService(Repository<EntityOne, Long> repositoryOne) {
        this.repositoryOne = repositoryOne;
    }

    // methods
}
```

4th - interface constructor parameter, concrete class member but cast the interface(this seems funky at best)

```
public class SomeService{
    private final RepositoryOne repositoryOne;

    public SomeService(Repository<EntityOne, Long> repositoryOne) {
        this.repositoryOne = (RepositoryOne) repositoryOne;
    }

    // methods
}
```

Even more so, does it matter?

If you could justify your answer with a "why" that would be awesome. I'm trying to be better as a developer and understanding why is the first step.

Comment: "*Even more so, does it matter?*" - Yes it does. We use injection to reduce friction. Ideally, we use injection at an SPI bondary: a module provides an SPI and uses some implementation of the SPI, so we should use interfaces in the classes of the module, so the module is not coupled to the SPI implementation module.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `5th` snippet. In this one you're free to use `RepositoryOne` or `RepositoryTow` or any other implementations that you probably create in the future.

```java
public class SomeService<T, K> implements Repository<T, K> {

    private final Repository<T, K> delegate;

    public SomeService(Repository<T, K> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(K id) {
        return delegate.get(id);
    }

}
```

In this case, client code will look like this:

```java
SomeService<EntityOne, Long> service1 = new SomeService<>(new RepositoryOne());
SomeService<EntityTwo, Long> service2 = new SomeService<>(new RepositoryTwo());
```